# Pop OS / Ubuntu 20.04; No network interfaces anymore

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

I installed Pop OS a while ago. Everything work fine.

A few days ago, I open my Laptop and my internet connection is lost. I check all settings and realize, that my network devices are lost in the configurations.

[No network devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB9nv.jpg)

When I boot with an installation stick, the devices are visible

[wired interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iKEx.jpg)

[wifi interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWN65.jpg)

How can I get the devices back to my config?
I try a lot of tipps, but nothing works.

Here some additional infos:

```
    ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:a9:3e:44:7a:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.241/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 5248sec preferred_lft 5248sec
    inet6 fe80::86a9:3eff:fe44:7aad/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:9c:67:24:4b:e7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff



sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp1s0
       Version: 15
       Seriennummer: 84:a9:3e:44:7a:ad
       GrÃ¶ÃŸe: 1Gbit/s
       KapazitÃ¤t: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       FÃ¤higkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.241 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:19 ioport:4000(GrÃ¶ÃŸe=256) memory:b1204000-b1204fff memory:b1200000-b1203fff
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp2s0
       Version: 00
       Seriennummer: d8:9c:67:24:4b:e7
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       FÃ¤higkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-7634-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:135 ioport:3000(GrÃ¶ÃŸe=256) memory:b1100000-b110ffff
```

With "sudo dhclient -v enpls0" I got the wired connection working, but it's very slow (max 3 MBit).

Comment: There is an option to disable networking. Accessible via the network button in the indicator area. Maybe you clicked it by accident? It is a persistent setting handled by network-manager. The installed system will remember. The live variant will have use defaults, thus starting with network enabled.

Comment: No. The interfaces are not available in the settings. It looks like, I have no interfaces anymore. Also there is also no option to disable/enable.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Is the output of `ip a` taken from the live system or from the dysfunctional one?

Comment: It's from my current installation, where there devices not longer available and visible. As you can see on the screenshots, wired and wifi interface working and are visible, if I boot in recovery mode.
Screenshot "no network devices" show after login in normal mode.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, after days of searching on Google, I just found the solution:

```
nmcli networking {on | off | connectivity}
```

With the nmcli command I could reactivate the network interfaces. Also after reboot, wired and WiFi is available again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I don't understand your solution. You did that exact command?

Comment: I use the command "nmcli networking on" to get the network interfaces working again.